# Assigning addresses to each other without using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote this random code waiting for some kind of error but it worked in a weird way that I couldn't understand.

```
void f(int *p,int *q){
  
   p=q;
   *p=2;
}

int i=0,j=1;

int main(){
f(&i,&j);
printf("%d %d",i,j);
}
```

the thing that I didn't understand aren't p and q the addresses of i and j which are not some pointers that I could store addresses inside of them so why affecting them to each other works and when I thought the i value will be 2 I was surprised that it did remain 0 instead the j value became 2.

Comment: Because you set p to q, which points to j.

Comment: `p` and `q` are pointer variables. They *hold* addresses. The same way an `int a;` can hold a native `int` value, `int *p;` can hold an address where (hopefully) some `int` value resides. `p=q;` says "make the local var `p` hold the same address that `q` does, whatever that is." So it shouldn't be surprising then thereafter dereferencing `p` is now similar to dereferencing `q`.  After all, they now hold the same address (which you would see if you inspected their values in a **debugger**).

Answer (score 1):

`main` calls `f` with:

```
f(&i,&j);
```

So inside `f`, `p` has the value `&i` and `q` has the value `&j`.  It then does:

```
p=q;
```

This copies the value of `q` to `p`, so now both `p` and `q` have the value `&j`.

Finally, it does:

```
*p=2;
```

Since `p` has the value `&j`, this sets `j` to 2.  It's equivalent to `*(&j) = 2;`, which is just `j = 2;`.

Upon return to `main`, the value of `i` is unchanged, so it remains `0`, and the value of `j` is `2`.  So it prints `0 2`.